# How do I access a httponly cookie (set by the client) on the server?

Tags: cookies, asp.net-web-api2, auth0, httponly, cookie-httponly

I have a Single Page Application built with React and ASP.NET Core 2.1 WebAPI on the backend. I am switching to storing auth0 tokens from localstorage to httponly cookies and have trouble accessing the auth0 token stored in an httponly cookie(set by the client/browser) on the server.

I am storing my auth0 token in a cookie and I send it to the server for validation. I am able to access the auth0 token when httponly flag is false, but when set to true, I am unable to access the token. I tried implementing a middleware to check the same and found that the token isn't visible when http only is true.

Answer (score 1):

So, after some research I just realized that httponly cannot be set by JavaScript and it has to be set only on the server side.